# Excel VBA not reading Date data the way I want

Tags: excel, vba

I have a program that is supposed to read the date from a cell. In that cell, I have given it the value of =NOW() just by typing it into the cell outside of VBA. The cell is formatted as a date and the format is: dd-month (for example; 28-Jan). When VBA reads the cell, it reads it as mm/dd/yyy 00:00:00 AM/PM. Is there a way to make my code read the month from the format I set? A section of my code is below:

```
dashpos = InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Cells(2, 15), "-")
curmonth = Right(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Cells(2, 15).Value, dashpos + 1)
```

The cell containing the date is Cell(2,15). I then go on to use the three letters on the month to determine the following month using a Select Case curmonth.

Comment: Why don't you just use the `Month` function on the date? What does your `Select Case` look like?

Comment: The format doesn't matter. The date is stored as a number in excel. Try this. `MonthName(Month(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Cells(2, 15).Value), True)` Will give you `Jan` in your case

Comment: All of these fixes did work for what I wanted! I ended up extracting the number and using a Select Case to turn the number to the first three digits of the month. Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If your format is *mm/dd/yyy 00:00:00 AM/PM* in the worksheet, then the month will always have **two** digits.  Therefor:

```
curmonth = CLng(Left(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Cells(2, 15).Text, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub testDateExtraction()
  'Next day in the format you use in the sheet (no matter, in fact...):
  Debug.Print Format(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Cells(2, 15).Value + 1, "dd-mmm")

  'Next month
  Debug.Print MonthName(Month(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Cells(2, 15).Value) + 1, True)

    'If you insists to use the string type data:
    Dim strDate As String, strMonth As String
    strDate = CStr(Format(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Cells(2, 15).Value + 1, "dd-mmm"))
    strMonth = Right(strDate, 3)
    Debug.Print MonthName(Month(DateValue(Day(Date) & "-" & strMonth & "-2020")) + 1, True)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

*I then go on to use the three letters on the month to determine the following month*

If you want to determine the next month, you can just use `DateAdd` and `Month`. The cell format is irrelevant.

The following returns the month number:

```
Month(DateAdd("m", 1, Cells(2,15)))
```

If you want it as a three letter string, for some reason, then

```
Format(DateAdd("m", 1, Cells(2,15)), "mmm")
```